# Seamless SFTP tunneling / jump box

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sftp

I'm trying to set up a way for users to connect to the same `gateway server` for SSH/SFTP (SFTP a priority, SSH nice to have) and have that `gateway` server route the users to private servers inside my network identified by username and the private host they want to reach. This has to be a seamless user experience, i.e - no special config file setup, no flags for command line sessions, and no special setting in UI tools like Filezilla.

What I managed to do so far is add this block to my `sshd_config` file in the `gateway` server:

```
Match User someuser                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   ForceCommand sftp  -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server
```

Now this works great when I'm doing this from a client machine:

`ssh -i id_rsa someuser@gateway_server_machine`

it will trigger the `ForceCommand` and give me an SFTP session to the `some_other_server` machine.

BUT

When I do `sftp -i id_rsa someuser@gateway_server_machine`

the connection hangs and eventually terminated.

so, the sftp doesn't give anything even with verbose - just hangs there - but this is what I get from the server side:

```
debug1: subsystem: internal-sftp
Starting session: forced-command (config) 'sftp  -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server ' for someuser from 10.16.2.149 port 58822 id 0
```

on SSH I get:

```
Starting session: forced-command (config) 'sftp  -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server ' on pts/1 for someuser from 10.16.2.149 port 33550 id 0
debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
```

I need to figure out what am I doing wrong here, or if there is a better way to provide this kind of connection to my users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ForceCommand sftp -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server
```

The above will start SFTP **client** on the intermediate server with its **textual** interface.  Your local SFTP client (`sftp` or any other) cannot talk to that. It needs **binary** SFTP **protocol**. That also explain why `ssh` seems working as `sftp` client. But it does not. It just pipes the textual interface of the `sftp` client on the intermediate server.

---

What you need is something like:

```
ForceCommand ssh -s sftp -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server
```

That makes the (most) remote server start SFTP **server** ([`-s sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#s)) and the intermediate server to pipe the **binary** SFTP protocol to and back (`ssh` just pipes the binary input/output of remote `sftp-server`, the same way as in your setup the local `ssh` pipes textual input/output of intermediate `sftp`).

---

But if you need both SFTP and SSH you will need to use [`Subsystem` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Subsystem) for SFTP, not `ForceCommand`:

```
Subsystem sftp ssh -s sftp -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server
```

Or to avoid having to repeat the tunneling separately for SSH and SFTP, you can use `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` environment variable to decide whether to use `-s sftp` or not.

If you actually know that the (most) remote SFTP server has OpenSSH too and the same path to `sftp-server` binary as the intermediate server, this should cover both SSH and SFTP:

```
ForceCommand ssh -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

Comment: thank you !
that worked:
ForceCommand ssh -i /home/someuser/.ssh/id_rsa someuser@some_other_server $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND