# sshd_config ForceCommand is blocking scp

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, openssh, sftp

I want to execute certain script on every SSH connection for admin user, for that I have added below lines to `sshd_config`:

```
Match User admin
  ForceCommand /etc/my_script.sh
```

Script is getting executed on every SSH connection of admin user. However it is now not allowing to do SCP/SFTP? Only SSH is working. I need SSH, SCP and SFTP access.

my_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

ip=$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $3}') 
if [ "$ip" == "192.168.200.101" ]; then
    echo -ne "Detected ssh connection over USB... \n" 
    echo -n "-----------------------------------------\n" 
    sudo -s . /etc/my_script2.sh
else
    echo -ne " continuing user login ...\n "
    exec "/sbin/console.sh"`
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use SCP or SFTP protocol, the SSH server must execute SCP/SFTP server application. As you unconditionally *force* `console.sh`, you break SCP/SFTP.

You need to evaluate `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` variable to detect that the client wants to use SFTP/SCP and allow that.

If you want to execute your script only with plain SSH terminal connection, but allow SFTP, SCP *and* still allow random command execution, solution is to simply test for (non-)empty `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` in your script. A native solution – put it at the top of your script:

```
if [[ $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then
    eval "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
    exit
fi
```

*(Untested + I'm no shell expert, there might be a better/more secure solution)*

---

Somewhat related question, with more technical details:
[Seamless SFTP tunneling / jump box](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510258/119732)